# Regex in Java with matches stored into an ArrayList

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

I have the following code made with the purpose of storing and displaying all words that begin with letter `a` and ending with `z`. First of all I am getting an error from my regex pattern, and secondly I am getting an error from not displaying the content (String) stored into an ArrayList.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.*;


public class RegexSimple2{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Scanner myfis = new Scanner("D:\\myfis2.txt");
            ArrayList <String> foundaz = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(myfis.hasNext()){
                String line = myfis.nextLine();
                String delim = " ";
                String [] words = line.split(delim);
                 for ( String s: words){
                    if(!s.isEmpty()&& s!=null){
                        Pattern pi = Pattern.compile("[a|A][a-z]*[z]");
                        Matcher ma = pi.matcher(s);
                        boolean search = false;
                        while (ma.find()){
                            search = true;
                            foundaz.add(s);
                        }
                        if(!search){
                            System.out.println("Words that start with a and end with z have not been found");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(!foundaz.isEmpty()){
                for(String s: foundaz){
                    System.out.println("The word that start with a and ends with z is:" + s + " ");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Always post the stacktrace and indicate on which line of the code it happens

Comment: It returns no errors. But my code doesn't behave correctly. First it says that :"Words that start with letter a and end with z have not been found". If  I modify my regex with the following general expression [a-z]* it will print a number of lines equal with the number of words with the following: The word that start with a and ends with z is: D:\\myfis2.txt ". What I am doing wrong :-(

Comment: Why is `z` in brackets? There's no point putting a single letter in brackets.

Comment: Also `[a|A]` should be either `[aA]` or `(a|A)`.  `[a|A]` will match `a`, `|`, or `A`, whereas `(a|A)` will match `a` or `A`.  Go with `[aA]`, as it does not need seem like you need to capture the match (which `(a|A)` would do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change how you are reading the file in.  In addition, change the regex to `[aA].*z`.  The `.*` matches zero or more of anything.  See the minor changes I made below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            BufferedReader myfis = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\myfis2.txt"));
            ArrayList<String> foundaz = new ArrayList<String>();

            String line;
            while ((line = myfis.readLine()) != null) {
                String delim = " ";
                String[] words = line.split(delim);

                for (String s : words) {                    
                    if (!s.isEmpty() && s != null) {
                        Pattern pi = Pattern.compile("[aA].*z");
                        Matcher ma = pi.matcher(s);

                        if (ma.find()) {
                           foundaz.add(s);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!foundaz.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("The words that start with a and ends with z are:");
                for (String s : foundaz) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Input was:

```
apple
applez
Applez
banana
```

Output was:

```
The words that start with a and ends with z are:
applez
Applez
```

Comment: Here is [a regex fiddle to test the pattern you've employed](http://fiddle.re/64xnx).  Yes, it will work for the inputs you considered, but the first character group (`[a|A]`) unnecessarily includes `|` per my comment on the question: the pattern will also match `|pplez`.  Here is [another regex fiddle with the unnecessary `|` dropped](http://fiddle.re/n7ez9), which you will find works as desired with no overreach.

Comment: Thanks I'll edit my answer without the `|`.  But the real problem was how he was reading in the file not the regex.

Comment: Cool.  Both are problems, though.  Getting the regex right is important.  All too often I see patterns that are underconstrained and declared to "work"; but if a pattern is over-inclusive, declaring that it "works" is really inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.*;

public  class RegexSimple2
{

     public static void main(String[] args) {   

          try
          {
         Scanner myfis = new Scanner(new File("D:\\myfis2.txt"));
          ArrayList <String> foundaz = new ArrayList<String>();


        while(myfis.hasNext())
        {
            String line = myfis.nextLine();
            String delim = " ";
            String [] words = line.split(delim);



     for (String s : words) {                    
                    if (!s.isEmpty() && s != null) 
                    {
                        Pattern pi = Pattern.compile("[aA].*z");
                        Matcher ma = pi.matcher(s);

                        if (ma.find()) {
                           foundaz.add(s);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                    if(foundaz.isEmpty())
                {
                    System.out.println("No matching words have been found!");
                }
                    if(!foundaz.isEmpty())
                    {
                        System.out.print("The words that start with a and ends with z are:\n");
                        for(String s: foundaz)
                        {
                            System.out.println(s);
                }

        }

    }





catch(Exception ex)
     {
        System.out.println(ex); 
     }
}
}
```